# var_dump is good colored with XAMPP or new EasyPhP, but doensnt list everything, how to configure it?

Tags: php, xampp, var-dump

var_dump is good colored with XAMPP or new EasyPhP, but doensnt list everything, how to configure it? For example there is an array in array, and its listed as:

```
array
...
```

I want to see it too! Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might have xdebug enabled on your host. If not, you can install it.

With xdebug you can [configure the output of var_dump](http://xdebug.org/docs/display).

Answer (score 1):

For displaying all recursive content with inifinite depth you can configure your Xdebug module of EasyPHP with [xdebug.var_display_max_depth](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_depth) variable set to a negative value (-1).